# Sorting ArrayList<String> by an Integer parsed from each String from Highest-> Lowest?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

For example's sake, I will say I have 10 Strings in an ArrayList which each represent a person's name and age:

```
David:43
John:10
Wilson:23
George:59
Pat:3
Tom:52
Sydney:32
Mohammed:72
Jay:34
Adam:18
```

We'll call this ArrayList "people"

They are all in my ArrayList. I am able to get the age by using

```
Integer.parseInt(people.get(index).split(":")[1]);
```

But I want to sort the ArrayList to print out the people from highest to lowest age. I was wondering if there is any way to do this. And if there is, are there more efficient ways to do it?

Comment: Use `Collections.sort()` with a `Comparator` that does the age parsing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a much more efficient, legible, and scalable option. Use Objects. Java is an OO language, and a `Person` object that stores `name` and `age` and implements `Comparable` to allow comparison between your objects solves your problem perfectly. Use the `CompareTo` method to define how your objects should be compared. For example:

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
  public Person(String name, int age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }

  public String name;
  public int age;

  @Override
  public int compareTo(Person other){
    return (age - other.age);
  }
}
```

Then in your code instead of having an `ArrayList<String>` use an `ArrayList<Person>`. Instead of adding `"David:43"` add `new Person("David", 43)` to your list.

Then simply sort the list like this:

```
Collections.sort(yourlist);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Seems like exactly what I'm looking for! I'll try it out, appreciate it!

Comment: @David Happy to help

Comment: Hey @nhouser9, it worked very fell, there is just one problem. It prints out from lowest to highest. Is there any way to change this?


Edit: I managed to figure it out, here is the simple solution for anyone that runs into this problem as well:


 Collections.sort(people, Collections.reverseOrder());

Comment: @David Yes you can simply change your `compareTo` method with any custom logic you want. To go highest to lowest, change the order of subtraction. You could even sort by name using `return name.compareTo(other.name)`. Everything pertaining to the ordering of your elements can be controlled by how you are comparing those elements.